# How to center "position: relative"-navigation bar?

Tags: html, css, position, center, navigationbar

How can I center a navigation bar with the `position` property set to `relative`? It's for [this website](http://cega.one/mangoomsorg/hem.html).

I've found several solutions for doing that, but that requires me to change the `position` of the navigation bar to `absolute`. I can't do that, since that ruins the entiry css style for the navigation bar!

```css
body header .bottom-header {
 border-radius: 15px 0 0 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 125px;
 background: linear-gradient(to right, #381107, #993013, #FF5221);
 text-align: center;
 
}
body header .bottom-header ul {
 position: relative;
 top: 32%;
 list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body header .bottom-header ul li a {
 transition: all .4s ease;
 color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 14px;
}
body header .bottom-header .button {
 transition: all .4s ease;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 top: 40px;
 margin: auto;
 min-width: 13%;
 max-width: 13%;
 padding-top: 8px;
 padding-bottom: 8px;
 border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
 border-radius: 12px;
 margin-left: 0.4%;
 margin-right: 0.4%;
 cursor: pointer;
}
body header .bottom-header .button:hover {
 border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
body header .bottom-header .button:hover a {
 color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<center>
    <div class="bottom-header">
        <ul>
            <li class="button" id="top" style="margin-left: 1%;" onclick="window.location='hem.html';"><a href="hem.html">Hem</a></li>
            <li class="button" id="top" onclick="window.location='om.html';"><a href="om.html">Om Mango</a></li>
            <li class="button" id="top" onclick="window.location='filosofi.html';"><a href="filosofi.html">Filosofi</a></li>
            <li class="button" id="top" onclick="window.location='personal.html';"><a href="personal.html">Personal</a></li>
            <li class="button" id="bottom-start" onclick="window.location='kontakt.html';"><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
            <li class="button" id="bottom" onclick="window.location='hitta-hit.html';"><a href="hitta-hit.html">Hitta hit</a></li>
            <li class="button" id="bottom" onclick="window.location='bostaderna.html';"><a href="bostaderna.html">Verksamheterna</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </center>
```

What I've done to center it (which really isn't a good solution) is, I change the margin on each side of the navigation bar depending on the total width of the page. Like you can see if you take a look at the css of the page i linked before. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make yout `ul` a relatively positioned `inline-block`and use `margin: 0 auto;` on it to center it. And erase all `width` settings from the `li`elements / buttons, so they can have the width necessary for their text contents:

```css
.bottom-header {
  border-radius: 15px 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #381107, #993013, #FF5221);
  text-align: center;
}

.bottom-header ul {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.bottom-header ul li a {
  transition: all .4s ease;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.bottom-header .button {
  transition: all .4s ease;
  display: block;
  top: 40px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  border-radius: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bottom-header .button:hover {
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

.bottom-header .button:hover a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom-header">
  <ul>
    <li class="button" id="top" onclick="window.location='hem.html';"><a href="hem.html">Hem</a></li>
    <li class="button" id="top" onclick="window.location='om.html';"><a href="om.html">Om Mango</a></li>
    <li class="button" id="top" onclick="window.location='filosofi.html';"><a href="filosofi.html">Filosofi</a></li>
    <li class="button" id="top" onclick="window.location='personal.html';"><a href="personal.html">Personal</a></li>
    <li class="button" id="bottom-start" onclick="window.location='kontakt.html';"><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
    <li class="button" id="bottom" onclick="window.location='hitta-hit.html';"><a href="hitta-hit.html">Hitta hit</a></li>
    <li class="button" id="bottom" onclick="window.location='bostaderna.html';"><a href="bostaderna.html">Verksamheterna</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In case you want the buttons aligned horzontally (i.e. other than in the code you posted), apple `diplay: inline-block` to the `li`elements, and maybe a fixed `min-width` setting:

```css
.bottom-header {
  border-radius: 15px 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #381107, #993013, #FF5221);
  text-align: center;
}

.bottom-header ul {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.bottom-header ul li a {
  transition: all .4s ease;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.bottom-header .button {
  transition: all .4s ease;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 90px;
  top: 40px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  border-radius: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bottom-header .button:hover {
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

.bottom-header .button:hover a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom-header">
  <ul>
    <li class="button" id="top" onclick="window.location='hem.html';"><a href="hem.html">Hem</a></li>
    <li class="button" id="top" onclick="window.location='om.html';"><a href="om.html">Om Mango</a></li>
    <li class="button" id="top" onclick="window.location='filosofi.html';"><a href="filosofi.html">Filosofi</a></li>
    <li class="button" id="top" onclick="window.location='personal.html';"><a href="personal.html">Personal</a></li>
    <li class="button" id="bottom-start" onclick="window.location='kontakt.html';"><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
    <li class="button" id="bottom" onclick="window.location='hitta-hit.html';"><a href="hitta-hit.html">Hitta hit</a></li>
    <li class="button" id="bottom" onclick="window.location='bostaderna.html';"><a href="bostaderna.html">Verksamheterna</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```